# Ionic 2 - ion-scroll doesn't pick content height

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

In my app I have a panel which shows/hides on the click of a button. This panel has a max-height of 300px.

The content inside the panel gets added/removed and the panel should adjust it's height to fit the content. Since I want to be able to scroll the content inside this panel, I've used a `ion-scroll`.

The problem is, the `ion-scroll` doesn't seem to take the height of it's content. I have to specifically set a height in 'px' for it to show it's content. Anyone know what I can do?

Note: Giving a height to the `ion-scroll` in percentage is not working either.

This is the structure of my HTML

```
<ion-content>
 <div style="position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; z-index: 1; max-height: 300px;" *ngIf="showPanel">
  <ion-scroll>Scroll content goes here.</ion-scroll>
 </div>
</ion-content>
```

I'm using Ionic 2 - Beta 10.

Comment: Give this a try https://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/vm-vh-units